# Assignin object to self inside class method

Tags: python, django, object, oop

I want to do a check inside model whether object already exists in DB or not, and if its exists to read all properties from DB and assign to same object.

models.py

```
class Obj1(models.Model)
    name
    prop1
    prop2
    prop3
    
    def obj_check(self, name, prop1):
        objects = Obj1.object.filter(name=name, prop1=prop1)
        len = len(objects)
        if len == 0:
            # Object does not exists in DB
            self.name = name
            self.prop1 = prop1
            self.save()
            return 0
        elif len == 1:
            # Object does exists in DB
            self = objects[0]  # <<< Is it possible to do like this?
            return 1
        else:
            # Something wrong, too many objects in DB
            return len
```

main.py

```
...

obj = Obj1()
check = obj.obj_check(name, var)
if check == 0:
    print("Such object does NOT exists")
    print("New object created")
elif check == 1:
    print("Such object already exists")
    obj.prop3 = "New Value"
else:
    print("Something wrong, too many objects in DB")
```

Is this possible/right to do like this?
**self = objects[0]**

I know I can use `try: .. except Obj1.DoesNotExist:` costruction, but wanted to create Object first and make less queries to DB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, reassigning `self` doesn't really do anything. It just reassigns the local variable, it does not modify the object.

You would want to implement this kind of method as a method on the model manager instead. The default manager for an object is the `.objects` property, but you can also [implement your own manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/).

```py
Obj1Manager(models.Manager):
    def obj_check(self, name, prop1):
        qs = self.get_query()
        objects = qs.filter(name=name, prop1=prop1)
        n = len(objects)
        if n == 0:
            # Object does not exists in DB, create it
            obj = self.create(name=name, prop1=prop1)
            return obj, 1
        else:
            obj = objects.first()
            return obj, 0

class Obj1(models.Model):
    objects = Obj1Manager()
    # ...

# ....
obj, created = Obj1.objects.obj_check(name='foo', prop1='bar')
```

However, it's worth noting that this already exists as a default manager method: [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

```py
obj, created = Obj1.objects.get_or_create(name='foo', prop1='bar')
```